# How am I supposed to flag a question for migration to another site?

Tags: support, migration, flagging

So, [here](https://superuser.com/q/700651/279815) is the question. I think this question belongs to [database admins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) but when I try to flag it, only meta, stackoverflow, serverfault, webapps and android stackexchange sites appear. Therefore, I flagged as it needs moderator attention and got declined.

[image]

What am I supposed to do here? Or any similar situation where the to-be-flagged question does belong to other stackexchange site which does not appear on the list provided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think a question belongs on another site, and it's not one of the pre-listed, then when you flag for moderator attention, you have to be explicit about where and why.

Your flag did not have any hint of what site you think it should be moved to. That's why it was declined.

Next time, mention the site. Give a reason you think it should go there as well.

Comment: Thank you. I'll certainly do that next time.